# How can I extract text from an HTML page and replace it with its summary on the same HTML page?

Tags: web-scraping, summarization

How can I extract text from an HTML page and replace it with its summary on the same HTML page? I have summarization techniques ready but I am unable to find a scraping and replacement method.

As I see every webpage is different.

I guess I need to have a way to mark and ID each position in the HTML file from where the text was extracted so that later I can replace that spot with it's summary.

Comment: You can do this by opening a URL connection, reading the webpage, parsing it in order to find the text you're looking for, and... well... replace it with its summary.

Comment: "...so that later I can replace that spot..." - why you need to do it later?

Comment: i need to it later to replace the spot with summary

Comment: but parsing is tricky here. i know to extract the text but how can id the spot of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You need to remember where you found the text to replace it.

Of course you could also search for the text a second time, but that won't be any easier.